# Repeating a process in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, while-loop

I wrote a code for a simple animation of four divs moving them to an arbitrary position created by random numbers. I just want to repeat the same process 10 times. I used the concept of callback functions but it didn't work. I used a for-loop , however the process is still executed only one time.  How can I repeat a process for several times?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {$( init )});

  var xRandom;
  var yRandom;

function createNumbers(callback) {
  xRandom=200+10*Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
  yRandom=200+10*Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
  callback();
};

function init() {

 for (var i=0;i<10;i++)  {
  createNumbers(process);
 }
}

function process() {
  var w=150;
  var h=150;
  $('.number').on("click",function() {
      $(this).animate({
          left : xRandom,
          top : yRandom,
          width : w,
          height :h,
      },1000);
  });
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 30px;
    font-family: "Georgia", serif;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    color: #333;
  }
  #ejer { 
    position :relative;
    width : 800px;
    height : 600px;
    background: lightgrey;
    font-family: "Georgia", serif;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    z-index: 2;
  }

#div1 {
    position :absolute;
    top : 50px;
    left :50px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#div2 {
    position :absolute;
    top : 50px;
    left :150px;
}

#div3 {
    position :absolute;
    top : 50px;
    left :250px;
}

#div4 {
    position :absolute;
    top : 50px;
    left :350px;
}

  .number {
    position :absolute;
    top : 50px;
    left :50px;
    width : 100px;
    height : 50px;
    background: yellow;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    font: 30px Verdana, sans-serif;
    z-index: 2;

  }
```

```html
<head>

  <title>A simple loop example</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="ejer" >
    <div id="div1" class="number">div1</div>
    <div id="div2" class="number">div2</div>
    <div id="div3" class="number">div3</div>
    <div id="div4" class="number">div4</div> 
   </div>

</body>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are tying to move the div 10 times upon click it. If that is the case they problem is with the location of your loop and the way you are adding the animation. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {$( init )});

  var xRandom;
  var yRandom;

function createNumbers() {
  xRandom=200+10*Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
  yRandom=200+10*Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
  return [xRandom, yRandom]
};

function init() {
 var numbers = [];
 for (var i=0;i<10;i++)  {
  numbers.push(createNumbers());
 }
 process(numbers);
}

function process(numbers) {
  var w=150;
  var h=150;
  $('.number').on("click",function() {
      for(var i = 0;i < numbers.length; i++) {
          $(this).animate({
              left : numbers[i][0],
              top : numbers[i][1],
              width : w,
              height :h,
          }, {
              duration: 1000,
              queue: true
          });
      }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 30px;
    font-family: "Georgia", serif;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    color: #333;
  }
  #ejer { 
    position :relative;
    width : 800px;
    height : 600px;
    background: lightgrey;
    font-family: "Georgia", serif;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    z-index: 2;
  }

#div1 {
    position :absolute;
    top : 50px;
    left :50px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#div2 {
    position :absolute;
    top : 50px;
    left :150px;
}

#div3 {
    position :absolute;
    top : 50px;
    left :250px;
}

#div4 {
    position :absolute;
    top : 50px;
    left :350px;
}

  .number {
    position :absolute;
    top : 50px;
    left :50px;
    width : 100px;
    height : 50px;
    background: yellow;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    font: 30px Verdana, sans-serif;
    z-index: 2;

  }
```

```html
<head>

  <title>A simple loop example</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="ejer" >
    <div id="div1" class="number">div1</div>
    <div id="div2" class="number">div2</div>
    <div id="div3" class="number">div3</div>
    <div id="div4" class="number">div4</div> 
   </div>

</body>
</head>
```

The big changes I made are

1. Pass the full list of numbers down to the animation
2. Add an additional loop when adding the animations
3. Add queue: true to the animations so they queue up behind each other

Answer (score 0):

You can implement something like a game loop.

```
var i =0;
function init(){
    if(i<10){
        createNumbers(process);
        i++;
        requestAnimationFrame(init);
    }
}
```

where you call requestAnimationaFrame at the end of the function you want to repeat.